# PopupMenu only working with this as context

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

When using this code to build a PopupMenu

```
PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getApplication(), view);
menu.getMenu().add("first");
menu.getMenu().add("second");
menu.show();
```

this error is thrown:

> java.lang.RuntimeExeption: Binary XML file line #17 You must supply a
>   layout_height atrribute.

When using `this` instead of `getApplication()` everything works fine.
What is the problem here? Why can't I get a reference to the context with `getApplication()`?

Comment: dont you want `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: @tyczj : See my answer and the article I link to. In particular the table in the Context Capabilities section.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this article ["Context, What Context?"](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/). It explains the differences between different types of `Context`. In particular look at the table in the section entitled "Context Capabilities".

In short, when you use `getApplication()` (which is effectively the same as `getApplicationContext()` for the most part) the `Centext` you get is only a partial one. As an `Application` doesn't have a UI there are certain things you can't do with it when it comes to UI elements.